# Google Verify the integrity of the ID token gettirn the ERROR : IllegalArgumentException

Tags: oauth, token, illegalargumentexception

I am trying to verify the google token ID using Spring boot.
I follow step by step [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth)

In the

`GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(transport, jsonFactory)
    // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
    .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID))
    // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
    //.setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3))
    .build();`

I use my **client id** from my google **app** in the valur `CLIENT_ID`
but when i add

`GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify("someText");`

**I got the following error**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:108) ~[google-http-client-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37) ~[google-http-client-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
at com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebSignature$Parser.parse(JsonWebSignature.java:602) ~[google-http-client-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdToken.parse(GoogleIdToken.java:57) ~[google-api-client-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier.verify(GoogleIdTokenVerifier.java:191) ~[google-api-client-1.24.1.jar:1.24.1]
at org.sid.InwiBoApplication.run(InwiBoApplication.java:59) [classes/:na]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:818) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
... 10 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have to use **`"someText"`** in  **`GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify("someText");`**

I have to use a **String** where the **format** is similar to **IdToken format**.